# Fixed menu with title div disappearing on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to combine the scripts of this template (I'm revising)
https://codepen.io/lydiawawa/pen/gEPpwX
to carry the effect from this example:
https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/JwFuy

The javascript I need to revise is as of the following:

```
/* JavaScript from: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed- 
   floating-elements/ */

$(function () {
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var top = sidebar.offset().top - parseFloat(sidebar.css('margin-top'));

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y >= top) {
    sidebar.addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
});
```

Could anyone help me to revise the script to achieve the effects?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the exact problem? Your provided script seems like to do it just like you expect it

Comment: @mrReiha In https://codepen.io/lydiawawa/pen/gEPpwX the side bar does not move like the example in https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/JwFuy. When you scroll down only the title div disappears, the sidebar does not move to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already set the position of `nav` as `fixed` by default which won't give you the desired result. You should set its position as `static` by default, and change the value after the document has reached a certain point by scrolling.

As I mentioned earlier, that script in the actual OP is doing the right job. The only thing I've done is to copy/paste that script to your example ( and some tiny CSS changes ).

check out [this revised version at codePen](https://codepen.io/mrReiha/pen/oVbjxE)